# C define method

Tags: c

```
#define x 10 + 5
int main(){
    int a = x*x;
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

Can someone explain the difference between these codes? first output is 65 and second one is 225:

```
 #define x 15
    int main(){
        int a = x*x;
        printf("%d",a);
    }
```

Comment: Read about operator precedence and why you should use parentheses with macros.

Comment: Use `(` and `)` to ensure correct operator precedence. `#define x (10 + 5)` would probably help. Currently `int a = 10 + 5 * 10 + 5;` which is 65.

Comment: in first case `int a = x*x;` is expanded to `int a = 10 + 5*10 + 5;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is related to the priority of operators in mathematics and in C. 
In the first case, `x` is replaced by `10 + 5` so `x*x` is replaced by `10 + 5 * 10 + 5`, which equals to 65. 
As suggest in comments, you should use parenthesis to avoid this problem.

```
#define x (10 + 5)
int main(){
    int a = x*x;
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Macros are not functions or methods. It is just textual (actually tokens, but for the sake of simplicity I will not get deeper into it) replacement done before the actual C compilation.

lets consider

```
#define x 10 + 5
int a = x*x;
```

if we replace `x` by the 10 + 5

```
int a = 10 + 5*10 + 5;
```

it is probably not something you want. If we add the parenthesises:

```
#define x (10 + 5)
int a = x*x;
```

the expansion will be:

```
int a = (10 + 5)*(10 + 5);
```

Comment: Macros substitute preprocessor tokens, not text. If they substituted text, they could form new preprocessor tokens, but they cannot (without the `##` operator). E.g., with text replacement, `#define foo(x) -x` / `y = 3-foo(x);` would become `y = 3--x;`, which is an error since `--` cannot be applied to `3`. But it does not become that; it becomes effectively `y = 3- -x;`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil bare in mind that the OP is a very beginner. I was considering if I shuold write text or token, but at this level "token" (IMO) adds another confusion.

Comment: Simplification is okay. False statements are not.